# How to identify what capture card is installed

Tags: video, multimedia

Yo! how to find out what capture card Im currently using? I'm using Ubuntu as an operating system. thanks. :)

Comment: Which release are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try System Settings by clicking on it in the side bar

[image]

Once it open, you can click on ***Details*** and then ***Graphics***

[image]

Or

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
spci | grep -i pci || lspci
```

then Scroll down to **VGA compatible controller** to determine the type of video card installed in the computer.  Then type

```
sudo lshw
```

Then type

```
sudo lshw -html > hardware.html
```

To get an easier-to-read HTML version of the report

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) i already found out what capture card im using. :))

Answer (score 2):

Type `arecord -l` in terminal, it'll show you the available capture devices.